# Ratio of reaction force - Principle of moments

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics, structural-beam

I am having difficulties figuring out how I can determine the ratio of the reaction force at B to the reaction force at A:

[image]

I am also asked to justify which reaction force on the plank is greater; I was mathematically able to prove it but not for the ratio. Please help thank you very much.

Comment: Use that the torque onthe plank with respect to the resting place of the block vanishes.

Comment: Why is this tagged with rigid body dynamics? This is a static problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the problem a little backward. Ask yourself what is the effect of each support force to the loading on the object?

[image: sketch]

The equipollent force from support **A** at point **C** is $F_A$, and the equipollent moment is $M_A = -a\, F_A$. The equipollent force from support **B** at point **C** is $F_B$, and the equipollent moment is $M_B = b\, F_B$.

For the object to be in static equilibrium, the net force must equal to the weight of the object, *as well as* the net moment to be zero as there is no applied torques on the object.

This statement is expressed as a system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns (the two support forces).

$$ \begin{aligned}
  F_A + F_B & = W \\
  -a\, F_A + b\, F_B & = 0 
\end{aligned} $$

Finally, consider the ratio $F_A/F_B$ and see that the weight $W$ cancels out, and only *geometrical* information is left in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

If the plank is considered to be massless,

Assume the mass of the box to be $M_b$ and $x$ the distance between $A$ and $M_b$.

$R_A$ + $R_B$ = $M_b$

Balancing the torques about $B$,

$R_A$ * $L$ = $M_b$ * ( $L$ - $x$)

$R_A$ = $M_b$ * ( $L$ - $x$)/$L$

Similarly, balancing torques about A yields,

$R_B$ = $M_b$ * $x$/$L$

The ratio of $R_A$ and $R_B$ can be calculated from the above two equations.